# MongoDb: sort by property in array of objects/documents with indexing

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a question about sorting a 500 millions records collection. so indexing is really important.

```js
{
   ...
   countries: [
    {country: "US", date: "2022-02-28T11:44:54.957Z"},
    {country: "CA", date: "2022-02-27T11:44:54.957Z"},
    {country: "BR", date: "2022-02-27T11:44:54.957Z"},
   ]
   ...
}
```

I need to sort by date for specific country.

**Example**: sort by date for only US country.

**Slow Solutions**

- using $unwind then $match and sort
- using $addFields by getting only this country object then sort by it.

so is there a way to apply sorting here with indexing?

Comment: The index is effective only in the first pipeline stage $match or $sort, or in certain cases like $match and $sort stages!

Comment: so that mean no way to sort by a property in array that match a condition? @turivishal

Comment: you can sort it after unwind or filter but it wont use index.

Comment: you can use index on `countries.country` multikey index, this can help if you have many countries, and each document have only few on them, after the match with the index, you can do `$filter` to keep locally only the country you want, and finally unwind and sort. Maybe try it, it cant fix perfomance, only make it kinda better, if its not fast enough, i think you should change your schema.